# Is it ethical to keep logs of a relay (whether it's an entry, middle or exit)?

Tags: relays

Is it ethical to keep logs of a relay (whether it's an entry, middle or exit)? Or should I not even keep logs to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Ethics are all just opinions. I personally do not keep logs, and the general consensus is that you should reduce logging to as much as possible. From [Tor's website](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/OperationalSecurity#MinimizeDataRetention):

> Audit your server's logging configuration and **reduce the amount of
>   information logged as much as possible**. Set your log rotation software
>   to delete logs after as short a time as you can manage.
>
> Remember, you can recover deleted files as long as the space has not
>   been overwritten. With mildly expensive computer forensics, you can
>   recover even multiple pass overwrites.
>
> **The best policy is to keep no logs.** If you must keep logs, consider
>   rotating them and purging the old logs with an overwrite scheme such
>   as Peter Gutmann's 35 pass overwrite using special patterns.
>
> EFF's best practices for online service providers
>   ​https://www.eff.org/files/20040819_OSPBestPractices.pdf.

Comment: Ethics are not all just opinions.